# Can Orbeon generate the schema of a previous form version?

Tags: orbeon

Orbeon provides a REST endpoint to get a generated schema for a form:

`/fr/service/[app]/[form]/schema`

This endpoint always seems to provide the schema for the latest published form version. I tried specifying the version using the header `Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version` but this seems to be ignored.

Is there a way to generate the schema for a previously published form version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the [schema generation API](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/other/xml-schema-generation.html), try passing the form version by adding the `form-version` request parameter.